# How to Turn Sharepoint lists into dropdown lists?

Tags: forms, list, sharepoint, drop-down-menu, cascade

I am trying to develope a functioning smart form on sharepoint 2010.  I want to avoid using infopath/solidQ at all costs.  Currently I have deployed the trial version of boostsolutions cascading forms, however I am having a hard time turning my "lists" into choosable dropdown lists, to use this 3rd party software.

The end result I want to achieve is to create a form where the user selects a dropdown choice populated threw lists, which "filter" the next dropdown option.  Think of it like Country -> Provence -> City -> Postal Code.

If anyone has a really ***detailed*** document or could go through the troubles of replying in ***detail***, it would be much appriciated.  I have been on the google hunt for a few days now.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

What about JavaScript with http://spservices.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=$().SPServices.SPCascadeDropdowns&referringTitle=Documentation ?